# Twilio/Django not receiving response SMS

Tags: python, django, twilio

I want to text a twilio number and start a series of questions for a user. If it is their first time texting, a new "Caller" should be created. If they have played before, I'd like to look up the "last_question", we asked them and ask them the appropriate question. My code below yields no SMS response and a Twilio error "HTTP retrieval failure."

In models.py I have

```
class Caller(models.Model):
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    from_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_question = models.CharField(max_length=2, default="0")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body
```

In views.py

```
def hello_there(request):
    body = request.REQUEST.get('Body', None)
    from_number = request.REQUEST.get('From', None)
    try:
        caller = Caller.objects.get(from_number = from_number)
    except Caller.DoesNotExist:
        caller = None
    if caller:
        if caller.last_question == "0":
            if body == "Password":
                message = "Welcome to the game. What is 3 + 4?"
                caller.last_question = "1"
            else:
                message = "What is the password?"
        else:
            message = "you broke me"
    else:
        new_caller = Caller(body=body, from_number=from_number, last_question="0")
        new_caller.save()
        message = "New user created"
    resp = twilio.twiml.Reponse()
    resp.sms(message)
    return HttpResponse(str(resp))
```

Comment: do you see any error when seeing above view from brower? what response did you get?

Comment: When i use the browser I get "null value in column "body" violates not-null constraint" This makes sense because I am not sending anything but from I send a text I inherently must have a "Body" being sent.

Comment: Yes that's true, could you test this 2 lines alone: `resp = twilio.twiml.Reponse()` and `resp.sms('some message')` ? I don't read the docs but what do they do?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio employee here - the issue could be because you're not providing a `csrf_exempt` decorator around this view. Django will trigger a security error because it is receiving a `HTTP POST` request from twilio.com. Django will not accept any `HTTP POST` request without a csrf token unless you make it exempt.

Have you thought about using the [django-twilio](http://django-twilio.readthedocs.org) package for Django? It will make your life much easier when developing with twilio. This is what your view will look like with django-twilio:

```
from django_twilio.decorators import twilio_view

@twilio_view
def hello_there(request):
    body = request.REQUEST.get('Body', None)
    from_number = request.REQUEST.get('From', None)
    try:
        caller = Caller.objects.get(from_number=from_number)
    except Caller.DoesNotExist:
        caller = None
    if caller:
        if caller.last_question == "0":
            if body == "Password":
                message = "Welcome to the game. What is 3 + 4?"
                caller.last_question = "1"
            else:
                message = "What is the password?"
        else:
            message = "you broke me"
    else:
        new_caller = Caller(body=body, from_number=from_number, last_question="0")
        new_caller.save()
        message = "New user created"
    resp = twilio.twiml.Reponse()
    resp.sms(message)
return resp
```

The `twilio_view` decorator will provide csrf exemption as well as ensuring all your requests are genuine and from twilio.com.

Check out the [installation instructions](http://django-twilio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) to get started.